# Concerning shorthand arguments in swift 3. New to Swift

Tags: swift, closures

Please look at the following code.

```
var shorthand: (String, String) -> String
shorthand = { $1 }
print(shorthand("100", "200"))
```

Ok so I'm trying to wrap my head around the concept of this. In my thinking if I change the second line to shorthand = { $0 } then I should get 100 back. However this does not work. I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(String, String)' to closure result type
>   'String'

How would I get 100 to return?

Comment: If a closure takes two arguments then `$0` can either refer to the first argument (if `$1` is also present), or to *both* arguments (if `$1` is not present). In the latter case `$0` is a tuple with `$0.0`, `$0.1` being the first  resp. second argument.

Answer (score 0):

To get 100 printed use this:

```
var shorthand: (String, String) -> String
shorthand = { $0.0 }
print(shorthand("100", "200"))
```

Because it returns a Tuple, and you need to access the first element.

Comment: Cool. Excellent. So being a tuple is a structure {0.0} would be saying give me the first value of the first element. Hence if I write {0.1} I would get the 200?

Comment: yes indeed! Please mark it as answered.